# How to improve curve fit for data with multiphasic exponential equation?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, data-fitting, scipy-optimize

I'm working on a project and I need to fit some data to the equation
`y = bmax_1 * np.exp(-koff_1 * x) + bmax_2 * np.exp(-koff_2*x) with bmax_1, koff_1, bmax_2, koff_2` being the parameters. I have tried using `curve_fit`, but the result is quite poor and give an R-squared value of 0.16. I'm wondering if there is something I can do to improve the fit?

```
    #Define model function
    def func(x, bmax_1, koff_1, bmax_2, koff_2):
        return bmax_1*np.exp(-koff_1*x) + bmax_2 * np.exp(-koff_2 *x)
    
    # function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
    def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
        warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
        val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
        return np.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)
    
    def generate_Initial_Parameters():
        parameterBounds = []
        parameterBounds.append([0.0, 200.0]) # search bounds for bamx_1
        parameterBounds.append([0.0, 10.0]) # search bounds for koff_1
        parameterBounds.append([0.0, 200.0]) # search bounds for bmax_2
        parameterBounds.append([0.0, 10.0]) # search bounds for koff_2
        # "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
        result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=4)
        return result.x

    column = input('Column to be analysed: ')
    xData = df.loc[:, 'T']
    yData = df.loc[:, column]
    geneticParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()
    
    fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters, bounds = )
    print('Fitted parameters:', fittedParameters)
```

The fitted parameters are `[1.24066146e+02 1.48240328e-02 1.34805335e+01 8.26108828e-01]`

Result of the fit:
[image: Result for fitting]

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. What is `geneticParameters` and `bounds =`? And what kind of advice do you expect without providing your input data?

Comment: ...yes...provide better start values.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't being clear. geneticParameters is the proposed initial parameters from the generate_Initial_Parameters() that I defined. I was trying different bounds to improve the fit, but it didn't work, and I accidentally left those on when I was pasting the code here. The input data is from a data file and includes over 10,000 rows of data, and I'm not sure how to put those here. I'm really new to this and the curve_fit worked with my other set of data which was not as noisy, so I'm wondering how I can modify it to improve the result. Thanks!

Comment: ...comment above still applies....it also seems that your data has a y-offset, which is not captured by your model.

Answer (score 0):

Since the initial values required by the iterative method presents challenges to evaluate, why not trying a non-iterative method which doesn't requires initial values ?

The method below comes from https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales .

Eventually if an iterative method is  of absolute necessity to achive some special specifications, the results from the method below can be used as very good initial values.

[image]

-

If you want to fit the function without the parameter a :

[image]